# not able to rename computer at windows OS level using Invoke-VMScript command

Tags: vmware, powershell-3.0, powercli

I want to Create a VMware VM using New-VM command and rename the VM name (at windows level) accordingly as per the VM name.

Something like :
VM Name = 100-SVR01-Jack
Windows Host Name = Jack-100

Issue : I am not able to rename the computer to Jack-100 at windows level using Invoke-VMScript command , seems it it not able to pass newcomputername into the Invoke command . Can anyone help me on this ?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Connect-VIserver $vCenterName -user $vCenterUserName -password "Password01" -ErrorAction 'Stop'

$CID = '100'
$CName = "Jack"
$ComputerName1 = $CID + "-SVR01-" + $CName
$NewComputerName1 = "SVR01-" + $CID
$sourcetemplate = "BaseWin2012R2"
$description = "Jack System"
$OSCustomizationspec = "SVR01"
$InfraResourcePool = "Infra-ResourcePool"


Function Create-VM (ComputerName1 , $InfraResourcePool,$description,$sourcetemplate,$OSCustomizationspec ){


New-VM -Name $ComputerName1 -ResourcePool $InfraResourcePool -Datastore "datastore1" -Description $description -Template $sourcetemplate -OSCustomizationspec $OSCustomizationspec -DiskStorageFormat Thin

Start-VM -VM $ComputerName1

}

Function Set-Computername($ComputerName , $NewComputerName , $HostCredential , $GuestCredential) {

$RenameComputer = '$hostname = hostname
                Rename-Computer -computername $hostname -newname     $NewComputerName
                RESTART-COMPUTER -force
                '
Invoke-VMScript -VM $computername  -HostCredential $HostCredential -GuestCredential $GuestCredential -ScriptText $RenameComputer


}

$HostCred = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential("Please enter credentials", "Enter Guest credentials for $computername", "root", "")
$GuestCred = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential("Please enter credentials", "Enter Guest credentials for $computername", "administrator", "")

Create-VM $Computername1 $InfraResourcePool $description $sourcetemplate $OSCustomizationspec;

Set-Computername $Computername1 $NewComputerName1 $HostCred $GuestCred
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically use the mandatory parameter tags when defining functions: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/05/22/use-powershell-to-make-mandatory-parameters/

Doing that may help you pass the variable in properly. Also you may want to change your preferred error action in case you're not seeing everything.